# System.FormatException: 24111: The well-known text (WKT) input is not valid

Tags: sql-server, geometry, spatial

I have a SQL Server data table with [X] and [Y] fields in Web Mercator Auxiliary Sphere. Both columns are of type `INT`. What's wrong with this syntax in my `SELECT` statement?

```
geometry::STGeomFromText(CAST('POINT (' + CAST([X] AS NVARCHAR) + ' ' + CAST([Y] AS NVARCHAR) + ')''' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),3857) AS GEOM
```

Here's the full error message.

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry":
>   System.FormatException: 24111: The well-known text (WKT) input is not valid.
>   System.FormatException:
>
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.Read(OpenGisType type, Int32 srid)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.GeometryFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars text, Int32 srid)

Example data:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why ‘’’ in the end? Remove the geometry conversion and just output what strings you create and see how they look. Most likely that ‘’’ is putting a single quote in the end, which is the cause of the error

Comment: I was overcomplicating things and @SamiKuhmonen was correct about extra single quotes. This does the trick. Thanks for the pointers!

`geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + CAST([X] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST([Y] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')',3857) AS WMAS_GEOM`

I kept trying to edit my original post and it kept saying code was not formatted correctly (when it was), thus just provided in a comment here.